# Does the Peano curve have length?

Tags: real-analysis

If so how much is it, and in what kind of measure? Or, when a curve is not differentiable, it has no properly defined length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length of a curve $\gamma\colon[0,1]\to\Bbb R^2$ can defined as the supremum over all polylines approximating it, i.e., the supremum over all expressions of the form
$$\tag1\sum_{k=1}^n|\gamma(t_i)-\gamma(t_{i-1})| $$
where $0=t_0<t_1<\ldots <t_n=1$ for some $n$. If that supremum exists (and is finite), we say that $\gamma$ is rectifyable. By this definition, $\gamma$ can easily be rectifyable without being differentiable. However, **if** $\gamma$ is continously differentiable, one readily sees that $(1)$ turns out to be $$\int_0^1\sqrt{1+|\gamma'(t)^2}\,\mathrm dt. $$
For the highly non-differentiable Peano curve, we'd have to go back to $(1)$ of course. It is easy to see that the supremum is infinite. Indeed, partition the square into $N^2$ squares of side length $\frac1N$. For each square, pick a $t_i\in [0,1]$ such that $\gamma(t_i)$ hits its centre. After arranging these $t_i$ into ascending order, the sum $(1)$ consists of $N^2$ summands where each is at least $\frac 1N$. Hence the sum $(1)$ is at least $N$.

Comment: One could also consider the [$p$-variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-variation) of the Peano curve, or more generally, the [$\Phi$-variation](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Phi-variation%22+Fourier) of the Peano curve. My gut feeling, without trying to look this up, is that for each $p>0,$ the Peano curve has infinite $p$-variation, but I don't have much of a feeling for the more general notion of $\Phi$-variation for the Peano curve.